# Getting form data and sending it to a new tab in the browser

Tags: php, javascript, cross-browser

Hi am creating a small form where you can place postcodes to get directions, it then sends this data with the URL of Google maps with the postcode in it to show the directions.

I was wondering is it possible to somehow get thenew URL i have into a new browser tab / window.

The idea is that the user input the postcodes and then presses 'Submit' which then takes them to a new browser tab / window with the new URL in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to do is to put "target=_blank" in your `<a>` tag or your `<form>` tag.

```
<form action='/your/url' target='_blank'>
  whatever
</form>
```

or for simple clickable links:

```
<a href='/some/new/page' target='_blank'>click me</a>
```

Now, you can't really control whether that's a new page or a new tab.  You can try to force it to be a new page by doing it with Javascript and calling "window.open()".